How to determine the algebraic structure of the space of algebraic gamma quotients?
When I recently saw this old question, I started wondering about the algebraic structure of those quadruples for a given common denominator $n$. E.g. for $n:=21$, it appears numerically that  $$x:=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{3}{n})\Gamma(\frac{12}{n})}{\Gamma(\frac{4}{n})\Gamma(\frac{11}{n})}=:\frac{\gamma_3\gamma_{12}}{\gamma_4\gamma_{11}}$$ is algebraic with minimal polynomial $$  3^3x^{21}- 108045x^{14} + 18000297x^7 - 7^7.$$ Otherwise stated, putting $y:=\dfrac{3}{49}x^{7}$, we have $$y^3 - 245y^2 + 2499y - 7=0.$$ Altogether, I have found that there are $54$ non-trivial algebraic quotients of this form (thus excluding those which are already known to be algebraic by the gamma reflection formula, so we only want $\dfrac{\gamma_a\gamma_{b}}{\gamma_c\gamma_{d}}$ with $a+b \not\equiv 0\pmod n$) with overall denominator $n=21$ and all arguments between $0$ and $1$. They are well-poised  (i.e. $a+b=c+d$), and all of their minimal polynomials have granularity $7$ (a term I came up with here, scrolling down to the end), with $48$ of them being of degree $42$, while $6$ of them have degree $21$ like the above one.
There are $12$ triples, like $ \lbrace \gamma_3\gamma_{10} ,\gamma_4\gamma_{9} ,\gamma_5\gamma_{8} \rbrace  $, for which the pairwise quotients are algebraic.
Now, the sufficiency condition proven by Koblitz–Ogus (thanks to K B Dave for the comment!) states that $\dfrac{\gamma_a\gamma_{b}}{\gamma_c\gamma_{d}}$ is algebraic if (putting $q_a=q_b:=1$, $q_c=q_d:=-1$, $q_j:=0$ else) for every $u\in(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times$, we have $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1} i q_{ui\!\pmod n} = 0$. This implies that if $\dfrac{\gamma_a\gamma_{b}}{\gamma_c\gamma_{d}}$ is algebraic, then so is $\dfrac{\gamma_{ka}\gamma_{kb}}{\gamma_{kc}\gamma_{kd}}$ for any $k\in\mathbb N$. By the reflection formula, we also get directly that $\dfrac{\gamma_{n-a}\gamma_{n-b}}{\gamma_{n-c}\gamma_{n-d}}$ is algebraic, too.
Building on this, we can obtain (the numerators of the arguments in) all algebraic quotients for $n=21$ from only a few representative "seeds", where taking $k=2$ is sufficient: the quotients of the above triple (yielding $36$ of them),  $\dfrac{\gamma_1\gamma_{4}}{\gamma_2\gamma_{3}}$ (yielding $12$ of them) and $\dfrac{\gamma_3\gamma_{12}}{\gamma_4\gamma_{11}}$ (yielding the remaining $6$ of them with degree $21$).
Now comes the interesting discovery: take any two of these quotients and raise them to their $7$th power, e.g. $\alpha=\left(\dfrac{\gamma_1\gamma_{4}}{\gamma_2\gamma_{3}}\right)^{7}$ and $\beta=\left(\dfrac{\gamma_3\gamma_{10}}{\gamma_4\gamma_{9}}\right)^{7}$. Then, while both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are of degree $6$, it turns out that the set $$\lbrace 1, \alpha,\alpha^2,\alpha^3,\beta,\beta^2 ,\beta^3 \rbrace$$ is linearly dependent for all such $\alpha$ and $\beta$. So they are not only algebraic, but also linked to each other by some kind of algebraic relationship of degree $6$ instead of $\underline{36}$.
Even better: it appears the same holds for any set of $7$ elements containing $1$ and six integer powers of either $\alpha$ or $\beta$, so they might be called something like "co-algebraic". In fact this further implies that the "space" of all those numbers, i.e. $7$th powers of the algebraic gamma quotients, along with all their powers, products and quotients, otherwise stated the multiplicative group generated by them, has only dimension $6$ in the sense that any set containing more than six group members is linearly dependent. A really remarkable fact! Unless somebody has discovered this before:

Is it possible to prove that? And to predict the dimension of that space?

And

Is there a relationship with the modular congruence subgroup $\Gamma(n)$?

My conjecture is that not only the (non trivial) algebraic $\dfrac{\gamma_a\gamma_{b}}{\gamma_c\gamma_{d}}$ belong to this space/group, but also all other algebraic gamma quotients, i.e. those with more or less than exactly two gammas in the numerator and the denominator. More precisely, not the quotients themselves, but raised to the power corresponding to the granularity.
I have tested this with some randomly chosen algebraic numbers like $\left(\dfrac{{\gamma_1}{\gamma_4}{\gamma_{13}}}{{\gamma_2}\gamma_{5} \gamma_{11}}\right)^{7}$, which also belong to this space.
Doing the same for $n=33$, there are $30$ algebraic quadruples, all with granularity $11$. Of these, $20$ have degree $10\cdot 11$, e.g. $\dfrac{\gamma_1\gamma_{12}}{\gamma_3\gamma_{10}}$, with a quite different algebraic structure, and the $10$ remaining ones have degree $5\cdot 11$. And, as may be expected, the space/group generated by the $11$th powers seems to have dimension $10$ (and again also includes triple quotients like $\left(\dfrac{{\gamma_3}{\gamma_6}{\gamma_{31}}}{{\gamma_8}\gamma_{13} \gamma_{19}}\right)^{11}$). Whole beehive here...

Algebraicity of $\frac{\Gamma(1/7)\Gamma(4/7)}{\Gamma(4/21)\Gamma(11/21)}$ follows from a condition proven to be sufficient by Koblitz–Ogus; Rohrlich's conjecture, if true, would entail that the condition is necessary (MathOverflow).

@KBDave Thank you so much, I wasn't aware of this sufficient condition! Of course, this settles immediately the question about $\dfrac{\gamma_{ka}\gamma_{kb}}{\gamma_{kc}\gamma_{kd}}$, even without assuming Rohrlich's conjecture. So what is remaining is "only" the final question about the algebraic dimension. (And of course one might ask how many solutions are there for a given N, but that boils down to a purely number theoretic / combinatorial question then $-$ assuming Rohrlich's conjecture this time.)
